# Accessing sub class's member functions through base class pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write a class that uses DOM to write a list of Registrations to file as XML.  The list of registrations contains three types of registration `Registration` which is the standard base registration class `GuestRegistration` and `StudentRegistration` which both derive from `Registration`.

The `GuestRegistration` class has a unique member `category` and the student registration has unique member `qualification`.

When I iterate over the list of registration pointers I only have access to the base class `Registration`'s member functions.  Is there any way I can access the subclasses' data members to use the getter functions `getCategory` and `getQualification`?  I've tried creating a `GuestRegistration` and `StudentRegistration` pointer whenever the class name matches either of the two, but get a pointer conversion error.

```
void RegistrationListWriter::write(RegistrationList r) {
    QList<Registration*> regList = r.getRegistrationList();

    for (int i = 0; i < regList.size(); ++i) {
        QString cn = regList.at(i)->metaObject()->className();
        Person tempPerson = regList.at(i)->getAttendee();

        appendRegistrationAndType(cn);
        appendAttendee(tempPerson);
        //this is where my issue starts
        if (cn == "GuestRegistration") {
            GuestRegistration guestReg = regList.at(i);
            appendAttendeeCatagory(guestReg.getCatagory());
        }

        if (cn == "StudentRegistration") {
            StudentRegistration* stuReg = regList.at(i);
            appendAttendeeQualification(stuReg->getQualification());
        }

        appendBookingDate(regList.at(i)->getBookingDate().toString());
        appendRegistrationFee(regList.at(i)->calculateFee());

    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do a `dynamic_cast` to both pointer types, and if you get back anything other than `nullptr` you will have access to the subclass methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to check for specific sub-classes:

```
void RegistrationListWriter::write(RegistrationList r) {
    QList<Registration*> regList = r.getRegistrationList();

    for (int i = 0; i < regList.size(); ++i) {
        Registration *reg = regList.at(i);

        appendRegistrationAndType(reg->metaObject()->className());
        appendAttendee(reg->getAttendee());

        if (GuestRegistration *guestReg = dynamic_cast<GuestRegistration*>(reg)) {
            appendAttendeeCatagory(guestReg->getCatagory());
        }
        else
        if (StudentRegistration* stuReg = dynamic_cast<StudentRegistration*>(reg)) {
            appendAttendeeQualification(stuReg->getQualification());
        }
        // and so on ...

        appendBookingDate(reg->getBookingDate().toString());
        appendRegistrationFee(reg->calculateFee());    
    }
}
```

However, I would suggest implementing a virtual method in the `Registration` class itself that your sub-classes can override to register additional items as needed, eg:

```
class Registration {
    ...
    virtual void appendExtraAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer){}
    ...
};
```

```
class GuestRegistration : public Registration {
    ...
    virtual void appendExtraAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer);
    ...
};

void GuestRegistration::appendExtraAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer){
    writer->appendAttendeeCatagory(getCatagory());
}
```

```
class StudentRegistration : public Registration {
    ...
    virtual void appendExtraAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer);
    ...
};

void StudentRegistration::appendExtraAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer){
    writer->appendAttendeeQualification(getQualification());
}
```

```
void RegistrationListWriter::write(RegistrationList r) {
    QList<Registration*> regList = r.getRegistrationList();

    for (int i = 0; i < regList.size(); ++i) {
        Registration *reg = regList.at(i);

        appendRegistrationAndType(reg->metaObject()->className());
        appendAttendee(reg->getAttendee());

        reg->appendExtraAttendees(this);

        appendBookingDate(reg->getBookingDate().toString());
        appendRegistrationFee(reg->calculateFee());    
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
class Registration {
    ...
    virtual void appendAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer);
    ...
};

void Registration::appendAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer){
    writer->appendAttendee(getAttendee());
}
```

```
class GuestRegistration : public Registration {
    ...
    virtual void appendAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer);
    ...
};

void GuestRegistration::appendAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer){
    Registration::appendAttendees(writer);
    writer->appendAttendeeCatagory(getCatagory());
}
```

```
class StudentRegistration : public Registration {
    ...
    virtual void appendAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer);
    ...
};

void StudentRegistration::appendAttendees(RegistrationListWriter *writer){
    Registration::appendAttendees(writer);
    writer->appendAttendeeQualification(getQualification());
}
```

```
void RegistrationListWriter::write(RegistrationList r) {
    QList<Registration*> regList = r.getRegistrationList();

    for (int i = 0; i < regList.size(); ++i) {
        Registration *reg = regList.at(i);

        appendRegistrationAndType(reg->metaObject()->className());

        reg->appendAttendees(this);

        appendBookingDate(reg->getBookingDate().toString());
        appendRegistrationFee(reg->calculateFee());    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer @Remy Lebeau  Why would it be better to create virtual functions than to use dynamic_cast or QObject_cast?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` has overhead as it has to perform an RTTI lookup at runtime to determine if the source object is related to the requested class and to return the appropriate pointer.  Also, if you add more derived classes in the future, you would have to add more `dynamic_cast` checks. With a virtual method call, the lookup is avoided.  Calling a virtual method is trivial, a simple index into the object's vtable, so the call jumps directly to the most derived implementation at runtime.  Much more efficient, and the calling code doesn't have to care about the details of the derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward C++ tool is dynamic_cast<>().

In general it is not good practice to initially design a project that requires such cast. Various design pattern may be considered.

I see that you are using `metaObject()`, so it means that `Registration` has `QObject` as a base class. In that case it is possible to use [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast):

> The qobject_cast() function behaves similarly to the standard C++
>   dynamic_cast(), with the advantages that it doesn't require RTTI
>   support and it works across dynamic library boundaries.

Comment: When I use QObject_cast i get the following error:

C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtCore\qobject.h:-1: In copy constructor 'RegistrationList::RegistrationList(const RegistrationList&)':
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtCore\qobject.h:465: error: 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private
     Q_DISABLbE_COPY(QObject)
                    ^

Comment: @user2094257 You cannot cast base class instances to derived instances. It is only possible to cast pointers: `qobject_cast<GuestRegistration*>(base_ptr)`, where `base_ptr` is pointer to base class instance `(Registration*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `dynamic_cast`, you could have the base class provide an interface that the derived classes use to write their class-specific data.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to make the methods virtual.
Non virtual method use the methods of the class used at compile time, virtual methods of subclasses are chosen instead at runtime.